# SFP proper address to read length

Tags: i2c, networking, fiber-optics

According to SFF-8472, there are 6 addresses (14 to 19) in table A0 for link length. And when I read a couple of SFP modules trough I2C, I see that more than one of these addresses contain value other than 0.

Example 1, I read value below from a 1.25Gb/s 120km SFP:

Address 14 = 120, Address 15 = 255, Address 16, 17, 18, 19 = 0

I understand here (from SFF-8472) the 255 means supported length is greater than 254 x 100 meters, and 120 means 120 km.

Example 2, I read value below from another 1.25Gb/s 10km SFP:

Address 14 = 10, Address 15 = 100, Address 16, 17 = 55, Address 18, 19 = 0

Here 10 means 10 km and 100 means 100 x 100 meters which equals 10 km. But I don't understand the value 55 in address 16 and 17.

I think I should check some other addresses to know that which length address (14 to 19) is considered as the correct length value, but I'm not sure what should I check.